# Java Syntax - "return true;" vs "return(true);" Is there a difference?

Tags: java, syntax, language-agnostic, return

I am reading an existing Java code base right now and I have encountered a strange usage of the `return` statement.  For example, there is a method `isTrue()` that is defined this way:

```
public boolean isTrue()
{
    return(true);  //Why? Notice: There is no whitespace between return and (true)
}
```

In all of the code I've encountered until this point, I've seen

```
public boolean isTrue()
{
    return true;  //What I normally see
}
```

This is pure speculation, but I assume these are the same.  So, **why would you ever do this?**  Furthermore is this a particular usage unique to java, or can this type of return be done in other languages?  I know this is a fairly trivial question, but things like this will bother me until I know the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: `(x)` is a _primary expression_ whose value is the value of the enclosed expression, `x`.  In other words, `(true)` equals `true`.  Why does Java allow you to write `return (true)`?  Because, given that we need parentheses in other places, it would only make the language more complicated to forbid them at top-level.  Why would somebody _want_ to write it that way?  Only the person who wrote it knows for sure.

Comment: Right.  My main concern was primarily with the absence of a white space between `return` and the left parenth `(`.

Comment: @heez Java is a "whitespace insensitive" language. This is the same reason why `x+y` and `x + y` are equivalent, as is `o.m(p)` and `o . m ( p )` - but don't write it like that! I recommend *including* the space [and omitting the parenthesis for simple expressions] or it makes `return` look like a method call or special operator - which it is not.

Comment: @user2864740 That's what I have been looking for! Thank you.  Very interesting, I didn't know you could separate it to `o . m ( p )` like that--good to know.  I agree, `return(true)` is definitely misleading and looks ridiculous.